# UI Agnostic way of passing around tree based information

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

I am writing some backing code that will tie in to a Winforms app, however I want to not make the code rely on Winforms code so I can easily move my code to something else, for example WPF.

The issue I have run in to is one of my operations I return some tree based information, in this specific case it will be filtered set of results from a `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` with sub-folders.

I know for my current case I can just pass the string path to the UI layer and let the UI build it, but if I did not have that already available format what would be the correct way to handle this? Should I make my own custom tree style class to pass to the UI layer or is there something already in the .NET framework that provides a generic representation of tree based information is not tied to something in the  `System.Windows.*` namespace?

Comment: Why not just pass the list of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`?

Comment: @HighCore I know the solution for my current problem (passing the path or the `DirectoryInfo` object). What I want to know  is if a pre-existing generic solution exists when I am working with other tree based information. I do not want to re-invent the wheel if something in the framework already does this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing preexisting in the framework.  I typically do something like this:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

In your particular example, `T` would be a `Directory` object.  You can always add another list property to `Node<T>` that contains the files at a particular node, or simply store the Directory object in `Value` and enumerate it to get the files.